# How to combine the results of two MySQL queries into one?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table like this:

[image]

How can I count the number of data that occur at the day of `2018-09-07` for each person, and the number of data that occur at the month `2018-09` for each person?

I mean I want to create a table like this:

[image]

I know that

```
SELECT 
  name, 
  COUNT(*) AS day_count_2018_09_07
FROM data_table
WHERE 
  arrive_time >= '2018-09-07 00:00:00'
  AND
  arrive_time <= '2018-09-07 23:59:59'
GROUP BY name;
```

can generate the number of data that occur at the day of 2018-09-07 for each person, and

```
SELECT 
  name, 
  COUNT(*) AS month_count_2018_09
FROM data_table
WHERE 
  arrive_time >= '2018-09-01 00:00:00'
  AND
  arrive_time <= '2018-09-30 23:59:59'
GROUP BY name;
```

can generate the number of data that occur at the month 2018-09 for each person.

But I don't know how to combine the above two queries so that `day_count_2018_09_07` and `month_count_2018_09` columns can be created in one query.

Here's the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00220d) where you can directly get the data in my question.

Comment: Thanks for providing a fiddle. If only all MySQL questions came with one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get both results from the same query:

```
SELECT name, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(DATE(arrive_time),1,7)='2018-09' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS month_count_2018_09,
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(arrive_time)='2018-09-07' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS day_count_2018_09_07
FROM data_table
GROUP BY name
```

Output:

```
name    month_count_2018_09     day_count_2018_09_07
Ben     3                       0
Jane    1                       1
John    3                       2
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is the most elegant one.

Comment: You can still do an improvement, replacing `SUBSTR(DATE(arrive_time),1,7)='2018-09'` by `DATE_FORMAT(arrive_time, "%Y-%m")='2018-09'`

Answer (score 2):

Try to combine them like that:

```
Select DayCounter.name, DayCounter.day_count_2018_09_07, MonthCounter.month_count_2018_09
from
(SELECT 
  name, 
  COUNT(*) AS day_count_2018_09_07
FROM data_table
WHERE 
  arrive_time >= '2018-09-07 00:00:00'
  AND
  arrive_time <= '2018-09-07 23:59:59'
GROUP BY name) as DayCounter
Inner Join
(SELECT 
  name, 
  COUNT(*) AS month_count_2018_09
FROM data_table
WHERE 
  arrive_time >= '2018-09-01 00:00:00'
  AND
  arrive_time <= '2018-09-30 23:59:59'
GROUP BY name) as MonthCounter

On DayCounter.name = MonthCounter.name
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
SELECT
  name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (arrive_time BETWEEN '2018-09-07 00:00:00' AND '2018-09-07 23:59:59') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS day_count_2018_09_07,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (arrive_time BETWEEN '2018-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-09-30 23:59:59') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS month_count_2018_09
FROM
    data_table
GROUP BY
    name;
```